# How to do force reload for the first time after the web app is deployed?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

I'm using React and Redux in my web app. I'm deploying frequently to production. So after deployment for the latest changes, we have to do

> empty cache and hard reload

in browser. Is there any other way to clear client side cache?

Comment: you can use the command "npm cache clear", it will clear the client side cache.

Comment: You can do this at server level (nginx or apache). I also used to face the same issue whenever i update my react app. I suggest you use **service-worker** also for this which solves many problems caching and PWA

Answer (score 3):

Its better to using hash file name to busting client cache.
webpack configuration: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/